# Named nets not connected in Eagle board design

Tags: eaglecad, board

I set up my schematic in Eagle and used named nets to make all of the connections.  If I highlight any of the connections in the schematic everything lights up properly.

When I switch to board design though most of the connections are missing.  I have GND and VCC nets, each with multiple connections which show up properly on the board.  But all of the point to point connections (connector to IC) are missing.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

[image: Eagle Schematic with net highlighted]
[image: Eagle board of same file]

Comment: I have never seen this fail like this. Do you have all of the copper layers visible? It's possible that some of the nets have already been routed, but you're just not seeing them. Any chance you accidentally ran the autorouter at some point? Otherwise, it may be time to delete all of the .brd files and create a fresh layout from the schematic.

Comment: All of the layers are visible and nothing has been auto-routed.  I deleted the BRD file and created a new one with the same results.  I found a possible fix here https://www.element14.com/community/thread/11927/l/lost-consistency?displayFullThread=true I'll report back with results

Answer (score 7):

The nets weren't connected to the actual part.  I was able to pick up each IC and drop it back on the nets and they all connected.  Ratsnest shows up properly now.

Comment: Ah, yes. I've run into that before, but I forgot about it.

Comment: I appreciate your help!